# Regular expression: how to capture word with only one repeated symbol

Tags: regex

Having an input of

```
aaadds bbbbb/bbbbb asdfdasf cccccccccc  \n
fffffff
```

What is the correct regex for getting `cccccccccc` and `fffffff`?

It should be something like `[.]+` except for the fact that dot inside the square brackets is literal and one can't simply backslash it.

UPD: also this should work for
aaadds bbbbb/bbbbb asdfdasf cccccccccc  \n s """""
    fffffff
adding c and """"" to the result.
thanks arshajii for the correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
(?<=\s|^)(\w)\1*(?=\s|$)
```

<kbd>[demo](http://rubular.com/r/U19WTVVPQ8)</kbd>

The problem with something like `\w+` (or `.+`) is that the `\w` doesn't need to be the same character all the way through; that regex simply means *one of more word characters* and not *one or more of the same word character*.

Instead, we can make use of capturing groups. We *capture* the `\w` with `(\w)` and reference its value with `\1`: i.e. `(\w)\1*` which does indeed mean *one or more of the same word character*.

Comment: What was the problem with the first approach? It would be awesome to detail that, as I had been thinking along the same solution, and the first few tests confirmed it.. Oh, damn whitespace, now I see

Comment: Thanks, this works. 
But for satysfiyng all boundary conditions it would be better to use \b(.)\1*\b
Just didn't know about using + and * with \1

Comment: @ppeterka66 Sure, I added some explanation.

Comment: You don't want `(.)` as your capture group as that will match any character such as a space.

Comment: Why are you using `(?<=\s|^)` instead of `\b`, since we're talking about word characters?

Comment: @AndyLester Using `\b` will also match the `bbbbb`s in the OPs example string. Which I guess isn't what he wants.

Comment: It will match the first `bbbbb` and then if checked again, the second `bbbbb`

Comment: Just as a little level-up: how should this look to capture '////' but not several whitespaces in a row?

Comment: @NoNeyNever You can try using `\S` instead of `\w`. `\S` matches anything but whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You want only words that contain only the same letter repeated?

```
/\b(\w)\1+\b/
```

That is: `\b` word boundary; `(\w)` one word character; `\1+` the captured word character at least 1 time; `\b` another word boundary.

Comment: yes, this works. But not for the case when the word has one single character. So it is better to use * instead of +

Comment: To me "repeated" means "more than once" so that's what I went with.

Comment: This is a question of definitions. I got used to definig repeated as one-or-more.